# TeamCity - Encrypt Connection Strings?

Tags: asp.net, encryption, command-line, continuous-integration, teamcity

I've been fighting with TeamCity and cannot get this command to succeed. (It works fine manually.) I've tried many things and surprisingly Google wasn't much help. All I'm trying to do is encrypt the connection strings in my web.config file after a deploy.

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "{mypath}"
```

Error: The configuration for physical path '{mypath}' cannot be opened.

I have it as the 2nd build step after my publish as a Command Line runner type.

I should also mention:

1. Yes, I'm selecting the folder the web.config is in and not the file itself.
2. Yes, the path is correct assuming it's supposed to be the one on the server. (C:\inetpub\mysite)
3. Most Importantly: I'm looking for a solution within TeamCity, not something manual or in my site's code.

Thanks!